# Neighbour Cells of a matrix

Tags: python

Suppose I have a matrix called "grid":

```py
grid = [ [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1] ]
```

I want to try and define a function that takes the contents of each neighbour in a 1 cell radius and add those values into a new matrix like so:

```py
grid = [ [3, 5, 5, 3],
         [5, 8, 8, 5],
         [5, 8, 8, 5],
         [3, 5, 5, 3] ]
```

Comment: Post what have you tired so far.

Comment: This looks like [kernel convolution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Image_convolution#Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that solution - quick and dirty :)

```
grid = [ [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1] ]

rows = len(grid)
cols = len(grid[0])

def get_sum_of_neighbours(grid, r, c):
    neighbours = [
        (r - 1, c - 1), (r - 1, c), (r - 1, c + 1),
        (r, c - 1), (r, c + 1),
        (r + 1, c - 1), (r + 1, c), (r + 1, c + 1),
    ]
    return sum([grid[r_n][c_n]
                for r_n, c_n in neighbours
                if 0 <= r_n < rows and 0 <= c_n < cols])

resultgrid = []
for r in range(rows):
    row = []
    for c in range(cols):
        row.append(get_sum_of_neighbours(grid, r, c))
    resultgrid.append(row)

for row in resultgrid:
    print(row)
```

without third party tools like scipy or numpy...

Comment: This is the one that I think best suits my needs for the time being. As someone pretty noobish to programming in general, it's good to be able to see how this can be done in a more detailed way.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to treat this as a 2-D convolution problem. You just need to define the appropriate mask.

In this case, you can use a 3x3 matrix of ones and zero out the center element.

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.ones((3, 3))
mask[1, 1] = 0
print(mask)
#[[1. 1. 1.]
# [1. 0. 1.]
# [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Now to the convolution:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
print(convolve2d(grid, mask, mode='same'))
#[[3. 5. 5. 3.]
# [5. 8. 8. 5.]
# [5. 8. 8. 5.]
# [3. 5. 5. 3.]]
```